# Riddle: A simple world for me

Tags: riddle

> Some think I live in strange neighborhood.
>
> Everyone who lives here has some job they have to maintain.
>
> Many people tend to forget about mine though.
>
> Some people might think my job is to only turn on a light. Maybe they're right.
>
> I work close to home, which is nice.
>
> But I am envious of my neighbor as he is always on vacation!

Who or what am I?
I hope this one can stump people a little longer than my previous riddles. :)

Comment: You're Homer Simson, I knew it!

Comment: That's interesting!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Excellent riddle.  :)

You are:

> the Scroll Lock key

Some think I live in strange neighborhood.

> The Print Screen, Scroll Lock, and Pause/Break keys are in a neighborhood not often visited.

Everyone who lives here has some job they have to maintain.

> Each key has a specific function.

Many people tend to forget about mine though.

> Scroll Lock is rarely used by most people.

Some people might think my job is to only turn on a light. Maybe they're right.

> When you press Scroll Lock, the Scroll Lock light on the keyboard turns on.

I work close to home, which is nice.

> The Scroll Lock key is right above the Home key.

But I am envious of my neighbor as he is always on vacation!

> The Scroll Lock key is right next to the Break key. (break = vacation)

Comment: I don't know how you discovered the answer, but I hope you enjoyed it (I'll just have to make it a bit tougher next time)   :)

Answer (score 3):

You are a:

> Refrigerator

Some think I live in strange neighborhood.

> This is the clue I'm least sure of... Kitchens aren't really that strange (though I suppose, at a stretch, it could be a ghost busters reference to Slimer).

Everyone who lives here has some job they have to maintain.

> All kitchen appliances have a job to do.

Many people tend to forget about mine though.

> You don't actively use a fridge (as in turn it on or control its settings), unlike most appliances.

Some people might think my job is to only turn on a light. Maybe they're right.

> Open the door, on comes the light...

I work close to home, which is nice.

> Stays put in your home, always working.

But I am envious of my neighbor as he is always on vacation!

> Most other appliances don't work all the time, just periodically when needed. The rest of the time, they're effectively on vacation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be

> Electron

Some think I live in strange neighborhood.

> Few know physics

Everyone who lives here has some job they have to maintain.

> Proton, Neutron, Electron, they all have a "task": to keep matter stable.

Some people might think my job is to only turn on a light. Maybe they're right.

> Electric current is made of moving electrons.

I work close to home, which is nice.

> Atoms are their homes, and electrons are very close to them!

But I am envious of my neighbor as he is always on vacation!

> The protons usually don't move, while the electrons do.

Comment: You seem to have provided half of your solutions as "electron" and the other half as "proton".

Comment: my neighbor=proton

Comment: Right... but if you are an electron, you are saying that you are envious of your neighbour (the proton) because he is always on vacation (even though he never moves out of the nucleus).

Comment: Vacation is intended as resting, I think. The electron has to run all the day long, while the proton stands still on its sofa...eheh!

Comment: Good guess, but that's not what I was thinking! (An electrons world is often not associated with 'simple') ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be

> Electric FUSE

Some think I live in strange neighborhood.

> Many cant find the fuse easily

Everyone who lives here has some job they have to maintain.

> current passing through the fuse goes beyond what the device is able to handle, the fusible link will melt and the circuit opens thus preventing electrical component damage.

Many people tend to forget about mine though.

> Many don't know the purpose of a fuse.

Some people might think my job is to only turn on a light. Maybe they're right.

> we check the fuse when one light alone shuts off.

I work close to home, which is nice.

> Fuse is in the Electric maintenance box.

But I am envious of my neighbor as he is always on vacation!

> There is always a spare fuse that not used, next to the fuse that is being used.